# C++ largest_free node function segfault Linked Lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am fairly new to c++ and I seem to be getting a segfault when I compile my code. Although when I comment out the largest=tmp->size; and largest=m->size; it compiles. I cant figure out why this would cause a segfault. Also if anyone has any recommendation on the code, and how to find the largest node in a linked list that would be awesome!

```
int largest_free(void)
     {
    FREEPTR tmp = freelist;
    FREEPTR m = freelist -> next;
    int largest = 0; 


    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {

        if(tmp->size > m->size)
        {
                largest=tmp->size;
        }
        else
        {
                largest=m->size;
        }

    tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    cout << largest << endl;
return largest;
```

Comment: Gettings a segfault when you compile the code indicates that the compiler is broken. Exactly which compiler, and can you make a complete example that can be compiled alone (doesn't necessarily need a `main`, but will need at least the declaration of `FREEPTR`.

Comment: Above comment assumes that you don't mean "when I compile and run" where you say "When I compile... ".

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I wouldn't take literary what he wrote.. ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: hence my second comment.

Comment: I have quite a bit of other code including a main and declaration of FREEPTR. I just did not include it because all the other code compiles fine without this function

Comment: I do believe that M is NULL and that is why it is not working. I have to manipulate some of my other code, although I am pretty sure that will fix it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should compare largest with all elements and set it to the current element. largest should be set to the maximum of largest and the current element, all the time.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
...
int largest_free(void)
{
    FREEPTR tmp = freelist;
    FREEPTR m = freelist -> next;

    // one option:
    //int largest = INT_MIN; // initialize largest to the lowest possible value. For int that is defined in the limits header as INT_MIN to -32767

    // or:
    assert(tmp);
    int largest = tmp->size; // init with first value.


    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {

        if(tmp->size > largest)
        {
                largest=tmp->size;
        }

        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    cout << largest << endl;
    return largest;
 }
```

think about your definition of "largest" for empty lists. You could pick the first element of a list instead of MIN_INT, if you never have a empty list. Depends on the requirements.

With a Macro like

```
#define MAX(X,Y) ((X) > (Y) ? (X) : (Y))
```

you can have a shorter while loop:

```
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        largest = MAX(largest, tmp->size);            
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
```

Comment: This does indeed solve the potential problem of `m == NULL`. But it also assumes that size is a positive value (yes, something called "size" probably is!)

Comment: pick `largest` from the first element.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, okay - see my edits. It can work now with negative values.

Comment: I agree with Karoly, use the first element as "largest" (if present, otherwise whatever default value should be).